# Update EditText Outside onCreate()

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an application I am making which recieves text through a socket and I would like for it to update the editText from a method that isn't part of the onCreate().  I have this method:

```
public void addToEditText(String message)
{
     editText.append(message);
}
```

However when I call this method the editText is still empty.  What am I doing wrong?

This is what my new method looks like and it is still not working:

```
private void addToEditText(final String message)
    {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                chatWindow.append(message);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need to give us more relevant code. `EditText.append()` is valid in and of itself, but we need to know where the call to `addToEditText()` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You Update EditText any where in the UI thread in its context. If you want to update the Edittext out side of the UI thread, then create a `Handler` in your Activity and use `Handler.post()` method

Comment: @Josh Make sure that you've create your handler object in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
private void addToEditText(final String message)
{
    chatWindow.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            chatWindow.append(message);
        }
    });
}
```